# How to write these 3 sentences with requests instead of urllib2?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib2

I am using python `3.5.2`.
My question is:

How to write these 3 sentences with requests instead of urllib2 in the demo below?

```
import urllib2

proxy_type=record[2].lower()
proxy="%s:%s"%(record[0],record[1])

#How to write these 3 sentences with requests instead of urllib2 below?
req=urllib2.Request(url=url)
req.set_proxy(proxy,proxy_type)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=30)
code=response.getcode()
```

**Edit:**

@MartijnPieters Thanks,there is another question,as follow:

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies={proxy_type: proxy})
code=response.getcode()
```

error:

```
    code=response.getcode()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'getcode'
```

`getcode()` belongs to `urllib2`,
whick function should I use when `urllib2` was replaced by `requests`?

Comment: `response = requests.get(url, proxies={proxy_type: proxy})`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! I have another question,see my edit content,thanks again!

Comment: do check out the excellent documentation for `requests`; see the [*Quickstart* section](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) for example. You are looking for `response.status_code`.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask this as a new question.